# A vector $x$ is orthogonal to a set $E$ closed under scalar multiplication if and only if $\operatorname{dist}(x,E)=\|x\|$

Tags: functional-analysis, inner-products

Let $X$ be an inner product space. Let $E\subset X$ be closed under scalar multiplication and $x \in X$. Then $x \perp E$ if and only if $\operatorname{dist}(x,E)=||x||$.

I am able to show the forward part but not able to prove the backward part i.e. $\operatorname{dist}(x,E)=||x|| \implies x \perp E$

Please provide some hints!

Comment: Indirect proof. Assume there is $e\in E$ with $\langle x,e\rangle \neq 0$, and show $\operatorname{dist}(x,E) < \lVert x\rVert$.

Comment: I don't understand.. If $E$ is a cone, which is closed under scalar multiplication, the $(\Rightarrow)$ is not true.

Comment: @JohnMa - I don't see that. If $v\in E$, then $x\perp v \implies \langle x, v\rangle = 0$, so $\langle x - v, x - v\rangle = \langle x,x\rangle +  \langle v,v\rangle$. Thus $\operatorname{dist}(x, v) \ge \|x\|$, and since $0 \in E$, $\operatorname{dist}(x, E) = \|x\|$

Comment: My bad, I mean the part $\text{dist} (x, E) = \|x\|\Rightarrow x\perp E$. @PaulSinclair . Let for example $E \subset\mathbb R^2$ is the graph of $y  =|x|$ and $x = (0,-1)$.

Comment: My mistake for thinking you were disagreeing with the forward implication. I should have checked your counter-example against the reverse implication before commenting.

Comment: @JohnMa The graph of $y=|x|$ is not closed under scalar multiplication.

Comment: @DanielFischer Assuming $\langle x, e \rangle \neq 0$ for some $e \in E$ can you give a sketch of the proof that $\operatorname{dist}(x,E) < \lVert x\rVert$? Thanks.

Comment: @Error404 Like in the answer. One considers $d(t) = \lVert x - te\rVert^2 = \lVert x\rVert^2 - 2\operatorname{Re}\:(\overline{t}\langle x,e\rangle) + \lvert t\rvert^2\cdot \lVert e\rVert^2$. If we have a real vector space ignore the $\operatorname{Re}$. If $\langle x,e\rangle \neq 0$, then for $t = - \varepsilon \langle x,e\rangle$ this is smaller than $\lVert x\rVert^2$ if $\varepsilon > 0$ is small.

Answer (score 2):

A set that is closed under scalar multiplication is a union of lines through the origin. So let's consider a line $L$ with direction vector $v$.

Clearly, $\operatorname{dist}(x,L)\le \|x\|$ always holds.

**Claim**: $\operatorname{dist}(x,L)=\|x\|\iff \langle x,v\rangle =0$.

Proof: consider the polynomial $p(t)=\|x-tv\|^2 = \|x\|^2-2t\langle x,v\rangle +t^2\|v\|^2$. Since $p(0)=\|x\|^2$, the only way for $p$ to satisfy $\min p = \|x\|^2$ is to have the minimum at $x=0$; i.e., to have the coefficient of $x$ equal to zero. $\qquad\Box$

---

For a general union of lines $E = \bigcup L_\alpha$ we have
$$
\operatorname{dist}(x,E) = \inf_\alpha \operatorname{dist}(x,L_\alpha)
$$
The only way for this to be equal to $\|x\|$ is to have $\operatorname{dist}(x,L_\alpha)=\|x\|$ for all $\alpha$, which by the above is equivalent to $x\perp L_\alpha$ for all $\alpha$.